# How to find file in path in Void linux

Tags: linux, path, void-linux

in usual Linux , to find a file in PATH , we use `which`

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

but in void linux , i got :

```
/sbin/git
```

#### how can i get the real directory of my file in my path ?

Comment: How is that a problem? Is the file not in /sbin/git?

Comment: Side note: [Why not use `which`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618)

Comment: the main problem that i'm install lua53, but not working , but old origin realse of lua is worked, also jdk is automaticaly install to /sbin/java, i can't manage deferent version if system hide my new app from path

Comment: check to see if the lua53 installer has an option, or config file, to specify where to find git.  or, if the installer is a script, edit it.  or just make a symlink `ln -s /sbin/git /usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 1):

Different distributions put some files in different places. That's normal, just go with whatever you find in void-linux and don't worry if its in  a different place than you are expecting to see it compared to another distribution . The only caveat would be if you suddenly find it in a real oddball location like /tmp or your home directory.

If its a standard utility installed by void-linux and its not in /usr/sbin, /bin  (or their sub-directories) then question its authenticity and ASK about it before executing it.